# numpy add variable number of dimensions to an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a way to add a variable number of singleton dimensions to a numpy array? I want something like [`atleast_2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html) but for an arbitrary number of dimensions. [`expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) comes up a lot, but only adds a single dimension.

The only way I know to do this is to compute the shape first and apply it, i.e.

```
import numpy as np

def atleast_kd(array, k):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    new_shape = array.shape + (1,) * (k - array.ndim)
    return array.reshape(new_shape)
```

Comment: Looks good.  That's just a variant on what `expand_dims` does: `a.reshape(shape[:axis] + (1,) + shape[axis:])`

Comment: @hpaulj I should have looked at the source. This solution seems more elegant given that `expand_dims` doesn't do anything better.

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant way to do this is `np.broadcast_to`. For example:

```
a = np.random.rand(2,2)
k = # number_extra dimensions
b = np.broadcast_to(a, (1,) * k + a.shape)
```

This will add the dimensions to the beginning of `b`. To get the exact same behavior as the given function, you can use `np.moveaxis`.

Comment: This works, but `broadcast_to` will do other things if you're not careful so it doesn't seem like the appropriate method, granted, so will reshape, so :/. It also doesn't fix the main issue of having to compute the "new shape".